# C Programme has stopped working while uppercase the Word

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, return-type, uppercase

This code is not returning Uppercase Word rather it stops working.Here is the code.Where have I made mistake?

```
char Uppercase(char country[]){
    
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            if(country[i]>=97 && country[i]<=122){
    
                country[i] = 'A'+(country[i]-'a');
            }
        }

    return country;
}

int main(){
    char country[100];
    printf("Enter The Country Name: ");
    scanf("%s",country);

    char x = Uppercase(country);
    printf("Uppercase is: %s",x);


}
```

Comment: Do you see any warnings when compiling? There should be plenty.

Comment: Aside you used `'A'` and `'a'` so follow it through and replace the magic numbers `97` and `122` with `'a'` and `'z'`. Or even `country[i] = toupper(country[i]);`

Comment: You have a potential buffer overflow, among less serious problems.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variable `x` as having the type `char` and trying  to output it using the conversion specifier `%s` designed to output strings instead of a single character.

```
char x = Uppercase(country);
printf("Uppercase is: %s",x);
```

that results in undefined behavior.

And the return type `char` of the function `Uppercase`

```
char Uppercase(char country[]){
    
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            if(country[i]>=97 && country[i]<=122){
    
                country[i] = 'A'+(country[i]-'a');
            }
        }

    return country;
}
```

does not make a sense. Moreover the compiler should issue a message for this return statement

```
    return country;
```

The return type of the function must be the pointer type `char *`.

Also this for loop with the magic number `100`

```
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
```

does not make a sense. The passed array can have a string that contains much less characters than `100`.

And using magic numbers like `97` and `122` makes the code unreadable and error prone.

```
if(country[i]>=97 && country[i]<=122){
```

AT least you could write

```
if(country[i] >= 'a' && country[i] <= 'z'){
```

The function can be defined for example the following way

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

char * Uppercase( char country[] )
{
    for ( char *s = country; *s; ++s )
    {
        *s = toupper( ( unsigned char ) *s );
    }

    return country;
}
```

Comment: I think using strlen would be clearer , and indexing into country

Comment: @pm100 It will be a redundant code..

Comment: @pm100 and traverse the string twice for no reason?

Answer (score 1):

Better use standard functions not magic numbers:

```
char *strtoupper(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    while(*str)
    {
        *str = toupper((unsigned char)*str);
        str++;
    }
    return wrk;
}
```